# Indexing into MeiliSearch - Apache Solr - ElasticSearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, solr

I am doing a technical study for three indexing engines (MeiliSearch - Apache Solr - ElasticSearch), and I have a different behavior when indexing in each of these engines, MeiliSearch indexes only 1017 documents out of 50,000, Apache Solr indexes only 800 documents, and Elastic does not idexe anything.
Can you help me understand what's going on, and suggest solutions like changing the configuration or whatever.

I know that it may be due to resource consumption, so don't hesitate to suggest hardware configurations that must be to index these 50,000 documents which are PDF docs.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide current configuration.

Comment: The VM hosting the application is a DEBIAN 10 with 4 GB of Ram and 100 GB of HDD which will be resized if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was because of a library (Debenu), which crashes with the large number of documents when parsing (50000 docs), so be careful which parsing library you use, in my case I had changed it to another one called spatie-pdf-to-text.